# Logging SQL queries in android

Tags: android, sqlite, logging

I am using the `query` functions in order to build the SQL queries for my tables. Is there a way to see the actual query that is run? For instance log it somewhere?

So far the best I could do was to have a look at the cursor's member mQuery using a breakpoint. I'd love to output the queries automatically though. This member is of course not public and does not have a getter.

---

Just for the record, here is an implementation of the accepted answer.

```
/**
 * Implement the cursor factory in order to log the queries before returning 
 * the cursor
 * 
 * @author Vincent @ MarvinLabs
 */
public class SQLiteCursorFactory implements CursorFactory {

    private boolean debugQueries = false;

    public SQLiteCursorFactory() {
        this.debugQueries = false;
    }

    public SQLiteCursorFactory(boolean debugQueries) {
        this.debugQueries = debugQueries;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor newCursor(SQLiteDatabase db, SQLiteCursorDriver masterQuery, 
                            String editTable, SQLiteQuery query) {
        if (debugQueries) {
            Log.d("SQL", query.toString());
        }
        return new SQLiteCursor(db, masterQuery, editTable, query);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there some way in `SQLiteCursorFactory.newCursor()` to access the `selectionArgs` to include it in the output to `Log`?

Comment: Just for record. ````SQLiteCursor(db, masterQuery, editTable, query);```` is deprecated since API lvl 11, use ````SQLiteCursor(masterQuery, editTable, query);```` instead.

Comment: How do you use the above SQLiteCursorFactory?

Comment: See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#openDatabase%28java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory,%20int%29

Comment: For ORMLite users: http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_4.html#Android-Logging

Comment: If you are using an SQLiteOpenHelper you just need to pass your SQLiteCursorFactory to the parent in your helper's constructor, like so: `public DbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, new SQLiteCursorFactory(true), DATABASE_VERSION);
        }`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can apply your own `SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory` to the database. (See the [openDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#openDatabase%28java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory,%20int%29) parameters.) This will allow you to create your own subclass of `Cursor`, which keeps the query in an easily accessible field.

**edit**: In fact, you may not even have to subclass `Cursor`. Just have your factory's `newCursor()` method return a standard `SQLiteCursor`, but log the query before doing so.

Comment: Works nicely but this displays the query before any arguments are bound. Is there a way to see the query after all supplied arguments are bound?

Comment: This seems to work for "read" queries, but it doesn't work for inserts and updates.  Is there a solution that also works for inserts and updates?

Comment: how to turn on query logging in general? where is the logging?

Answer (score 38):

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.SQLiteStatements VERBOSE
```

Don't forget to restart your app after setting this property.

It is also possible to enable logging of execution time. More details are availabe here:  http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDebug.java

Comment: Restarting your app might not be enough. If not, run these too:

`adb shell stop`

`adb shell start`

That will restart everything and you will start to see a lot of SQL.

Comment: I didn't manage to enable SQLite verbose logging, even though according https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/android-cts-7.0_r17/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDebug.java , logging option is valid and nothing has changed.

Comment: Where is the logging? logcat?

Comment: The logs appear in logcat, make sure you don't have a filter enabled, the logs are not associated with your application id. Also, if you want to disable the logs again: `adb shell setprop log.tag.SQLiteStatements INFO`

Comment: Same query is printed multiple times. Is that the case for you as well? This is making hard to optimize things

Answer (score 23):

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.SQLiteLog V
adb shell setprop log.tag.SQLiteStatements V
adb shell stop
adb shell start
```

Comment: For missing uid -> `adb shell su 0 start` `adb shell su 0 stop`

Comment: this setting can be reversed by replacing the `V` with `D` since these are the shortcuts for the logging levels VERBOSE and DEBUG.

Comment: Thanks! I was missing line `adb shell setprop log.tag.SQLiteLog V` and it didn't want to work. Now it does!

Answer (score 5):

Using an `SQLiteQueryBuilder` it's painfully simple. `buildQuery()` returns a raw sql string, which can then be logged:

```
SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
qb.setTables(ExampleTable.TABLE_NAME);
String sql = qb.buildQuery(projection, selection, null, null, sortOrder, null);
Log.d("Example", sql);
```

Comment: deprecated since API leve 11 [source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html)

Answer (score 3):

So far the best I could do was to have a look at the cursor's member mQuery using a breakpoint. This member is of course not public and does not have a getter, hence, no way to output it. Any better suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQLiteDatabase with it's standard methods as insert, update and delete custom CursorFactory will not be working.

I implemented my not very great but working solution based on SQLiteDatabase class. It just repeats logic of insert, update and delete methods but without statements and actually doing the logging of SQL statements.

```
public class SQLiteStatementsLogger {

    private static final String TAG = SQLiteStatementsLogger.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final String[] CONFLICT_VALUES = new String[]
            {"", " OR ROLLBACK ", " OR ABORT ", " OR FAIL ", " OR IGNORE ", " OR REPLACE "};

    public void logInsert(String table, String nullColumnHack, ContentValues values) {
        logInsertWithOnConflict(table, nullColumnHack, values, 0);
    }

    public static void logInsertWithOnConflict(String table, String nullColumnHack,
                                     ContentValues initialValues, int conflictAlgorithm) {
        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
        sql.append("INSERT");
        sql.append(CONFLICT_VALUES[conflictAlgorithm]);
        sql.append(" INTO ");
        sql.append(table);
        sql.append('(');

        Object[] bindArgs = null;
        int size = (initialValues != null && initialValues.size() > 0)
                ? initialValues.size() : 0;
        if (size > 0) {
            bindArgs = new Object[size];
            int i = 0;
            for (String colName : initialValues.keySet()) {
                sql.append((i > 0) ? "," : "");
                sql.append(colName);
                bindArgs[i++] = initialValues.get(colName);
            }
            sql.append(')');
            sql.append(" VALUES (");
            for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                sql.append((i > 0) ? ",?" : "?");
            }
        } else {
            sql.append(nullColumnHack + ") VALUES (NULL");
        }
        sql.append(')');
        sql.append(". (");
        for (Object arg : bindArgs) {
            sql.append(String.valueOf(arg)).append(",");
        }
        sql.deleteCharAt(sql.length()-1).append(')');
        Log.d(TAG, sql.toString());
    }

    public static void logUpdate(String table, ContentValues values, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs) {
        logUpdateWithOnConflict(table, values, whereClause, whereArgs, 0);
    }

    public static void logUpdateWithOnConflict(String table, ContentValues values,
                                        String whereClause, String[] whereArgs, int conflictAlgorithm) {

        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder(120);
        sql.append("UPDATE ");
        sql.append(CONFLICT_VALUES[conflictAlgorithm]);
        sql.append(table);
        sql.append(" SET ");

        // move all bind args to one array
        int setValuesSize = values.size();
        int bindArgsSize = (whereArgs == null) ? setValuesSize : (setValuesSize + whereArgs.length);
        Object[] bindArgs = new Object[bindArgsSize];
        int i = 0;
        for (String colName : values.keySet()) {
            sql.append((i > 0) ? "," : "");
            sql.append(colName);
            bindArgs[i++] = values.get(colName);
            sql.append("=?");
        }
        if (whereArgs != null) {
            for (i = setValuesSize; i < bindArgsSize; i++) {
                bindArgs[i] = whereArgs[i - setValuesSize];
            }
        }
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(whereClause)) {
            sql.append(" WHERE ");
            sql.append(whereClause);
        }
        sql.append(". (");
        for (Object arg : bindArgs) {
            sql.append(String.valueOf(arg)).append(",");
        }
        sql.deleteCharAt(sql.length()-1).append(')');
        Log.d(TAG, sql.toString());
    }

    public static void logDelete(String table, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs) {
        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder("DELETE FROM " + table);
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(whereClause)) {
            sql.append(" WHERE " + whereClause);
            sql.append(". (");
            for (Object arg : whereArgs) {
                sql.append(String.valueOf(arg)).append(",");
            }
            sql.deleteCharAt(sql.length()-1).append(')');
        }
        Log.d(TAG, sql.toString());
    }
}
```

Be aware not to use the logger in release versions. It might increase time of queries executing.
You can check if the build is in debug mode with this code line:

```
0 != (getApplicationInfo().flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE)
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is for once off scenario, I would suggest injecting an error (e.g. type in expression like LIEK instead of LIKE!) and watch the Eclipse LogCat for any errors! HTH!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a ContentProvider to access the DB, this is how I got it logging the queries. Not a perfect solution, but it works for development

```
@Override
  public boolean onCreate() {
    dbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(getContext());
    database=dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    if(!database.isReadOnly())
      database.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
    return true;
  }            

  SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory cursorFactory = new SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory() {      
    @Override
    public Cursor newCursor(SQLiteDatabase db, SQLiteCursorDriver masterQuery, String editTable, SQLiteQuery query) {
      Log.d(TAG, "Query: "+query);

      return new SQLiteCursor(db, masterQuery, editTable, query);
    }
  };

  @Override
  public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
      String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    String table =getTableName(uri);

    if(Constants.LOG_QUERIES){
      database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(database.getPath(), cursorFactory);
    }

    Cursor cursor =database.query(table,  projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    return cursor;
  }
```

It'll throw a DatabaseNotClosed exception, but you'll be able to see the query

Answer (score -6):

Personnally I log text using `java.util.Log` and the `Log.w("MYAPPNAME", "My text...")` function. It shows up in the Log view of Eclipse and it can be filtered to output only the logs for "MYAPPNAME".

Comment: -1: It does not help to log the SQL query which cannot be accessed.