# Logging SQL statements using SQLiteDatabase

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to see the SQL statements generated by SQLiteDatabase, to understand why something is wrong. Is there a way to make SQLiteDatabase log to logcat?

Thanks,
  Itay.

EDIT: This is not the same as [Logging SQL queries in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966584/logging-sql-queries-in-android), as I'm trying to log insert and update statements - I don't have a cursor.

Comment: Seems that you are asking the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966584/logging-sql-queries-in-android

Comment: No, not exactly, I don't have a cursor, I want to log insert and update statements (although logging queries is also a good idea...). I'll update to make sure.

Answer (score 2):

You have to implement it by yourself using trace API,so you can implement the callback of [SQLite Trace](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/profile.html) :

> The callback function registered by sqlite3_trace() is invoked at
>   various times when an SQL statement is being run by sqlite3_step().
>   The sqlite3_trace() callback is invoked with a UTF-8 rendering of the
>   SQL statement text as the statement first begins executing. Additional
>   sqlite3_trace() callbacks might occur as each triggered subprogram is
>   entered. The callbacks for triggers contain a UTF-8 SQL comment that
>   identifies the trigger.
>
> The callback function registered by sqlite3_profile() is invoked as
>   each SQL statement finishes. The profile callback contains the
>   original statement text and an estimate of wall-clock time of how long
>   that statement took to run. The profile callback time is in units of
>   nanoseconds, however the current implementation is only capable of
>   millisecond resolution so the six least significant digits in the time
>   are meaningless. Future versions of SQLite might provide greater
>   resolution on the profiler callback. The sqlite3_profile() function is
>   considered experimental and is subject to change in future versions of
>   SQLite.

Comment: Ahhh, now I need to find out how to implement those when I can't write C functions. Any ideas? A preliminary Google search wasn't very helpful.

Comment: The SQLite C API is not available in Android, unless you use the NDK.