# Are there any tools for monitoring database during debugging in android?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I want to monitor the contents of my database during debugging, i.e, I want to see all the rows in the tables, and see the updates as and when they take place. Currently, I'm using android.util.Log. But, if there is a better way to do it, that would be nice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The database file is in the /data/data/package_name/database

You can:

1. use adb shell, use command "sqlite3 your_database" to manage the database, also there exists a tool in sdk called sqlite3 (a command line tool)
2. push the database file out, use a sqlite browse tool to check for details (tools such as sqliteadmin, sqlitebrowser)

Comment: Thanks, I'll check the mentioned tools out. But I think that would still not give me an insight of what is happening as the statements are being executed..

Comment: :) hope it can help you, although the method is still a bit inconvenient

Answer (score 0):

I asked the same question before: [Logging SQL statements using SQLiteDatabase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200332/logging-sql-statements-using-sqlitedatabase) . Seems like there's no decent logging tool for SQLite on Android. It is a real shame.