# Is there some way to get the SQL string generated by SQLiteDatabase.query()?

Tags: android, string, sqlite

To help with debugging, I'd like to output (to `Log`) the query generated by a call to `SQLiteDatabase.query()`.  Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this is answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966584/logging-sql-queries-in-android

Comment: try to use SQLiteQueryBuilder.