# Android finding all the commands ran on a database using adb

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have a database in my android app. 
I am creating a table in that database and adding rows to that table. 
Over the lifetime of my the table's rows get added/modified/deleted.

I want to debug one particular row to see if it is getting set to a particular value ever or not.

Is there a way I can find the sequence of all the commands ran on the database from the beginning of the app ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Logging SQL queries in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966584/logging-sql-queries-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

`adb shell setprop log.tag.SQLiteStatements VERBOSE`

or

You can apply your own SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory to the database. (See the openDatabase parameters.) This will allow you to create your own subclass of Cursor, which keeps the query in an easily accessible field.

edit: In fact, you may not even have to subclass Cursor. Just have your factory's newCursor() method return a standard SQLiteCursor, but log the query before doing so.

Source: [Logging SQL queries in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966584/logging-sql-queries-in-android)

Comment: the following command worked for me: sqlite3 mydatabase.db ".dump". This gave an entire list of commands that were executed on mydatabase.