# updating and deleting row in listview

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I know the question is not new, but all the other examples I found here didnt work. Thats why I am writing to you.

I created a book application, where you can save bookdata from googlebooks and can save the data into an sqlite db. The bookdata will be displayed in a listview.
If you click on a row, all the data of the row will be displayed in EdittExts in another activity - Looks like Detailed book view. 
Some example pictures: [Listview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/666uZ.png) ; [detailed bookview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoYiB.png)

Now I want to give the possibility to the user to edit these bookinfos.
I implemented some code to update and delte the info and I get the info from the Logcat, that the Db is created but when I go back to the ListView no Data is updated or deleted.

I used a video called "Android Studio Tutorial - 37 - Update Database" from youtube to convert for my solution

Maybe you can help me.

Following my code for the Book Info:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_book_info);
        bookDBHelper = new BookDBHelper(this);
        Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Lobster.ttf");
        TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourbookinfo);
        myTextView.setTypeface(myTypeface);

        btn_update = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_update);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        String secret_title = intent.getStringExtra(BookDataListActivity.EXTRA_MSG1);
        Secret_editText_title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.secret_edittext_title);
        Secret_editText_title.setText(secret_title);

        String book_title = intent.getStringExtra(BookDataListActivity.EXTRA_MSG1);
        passedbooktitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passed_booktitle);
        passedbooktitle.setText(book_title);

        String book_author = intent.getStringExtra(BookDataListActivity.EXTRA_MSG2);
        passedbookauthor = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passed_bookauthor);
        passedbookauthor.setText(book_author);

        String book_date = intent.getStringExtra(BookDataListActivity.EXTRA_MSG3);
        passedbookdate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passed_bookdate);
        passedbookdate.setText(book_date);

        String book_rating = intent.getStringExtra(BookDataListActivity.EXTRA_MSG4);
        passedbookrating = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passed_bookrating);
        passedbookrating.setText(book_rating);

        String book_shelf = intent.getStringExtra(BookDataListActivity.EXTRA_MSG5);
        passedbookshelf = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passed_bookshelf);
        passedbookshelf.setText(book_shelf);

    }


    public void updateBookInfo(View view){
        bookDBHelper = new BookDBHelper(getApplicationContext());
        sqLiteDatabaseBooks = bookDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        secret_editText_titel = Secret_editText_title.getText().toString();

        String booktitle, bookauthor, bookdate, bookrating, bookshelf;
        booktitle = passedbooktitle.getText().toString();
        bookauthor = passedbookauthor.getText().toString();
        bookdate = passedbookdate.getText().toString();
        bookrating = passedbookrating.getText().toString();
        bookshelf = passedbookshelf.getText().toString();
        int count = bookDBHelper.updateEditedBookInfo(secret_editText_titel,
                booktitle,bookauthor, bookdate, bookrating, bookshelf, sqLiteDatabaseBooks);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), count+" book updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();

    }

    public void deleteBook(View view){
        bookDBHelper = new BookDBHelper(getApplicationContext());
        sqLiteDatabaseBooks = bookDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        bookDBHelper.deleteBookInformation(secret_editText_titel, sqLiteDatabaseBooks);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Book deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

And for my BookDBHelper:

```
public int updateEditedBookInfo(String old_title, String new_title, String new_author,
                                     String new_date, String new_rating,
                                     String new_shelf, SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase){
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(BookContent.NewBookInfo.BOOK_TITLE, new_title);
        contentValues.put(BookContent.NewBookInfo.BOOK_AUTHOR, new_author);
        contentValues.put(BookContent.NewBookInfo.BOOK_DATE, new_date);
        contentValues.put(BookContent.NewBookInfo.BOOK_RATING, new_rating);
        contentValues.put(BookContent.NewBookInfo.BOOK_SHELF, new_shelf);

        String selection = BookContent.NewBookInfo.BOOK_TITLE + " = ?";
        String [] selection_args = {old_title};
        int count =  sqLiteDatabase.update(BookContent.NewBookInfo.TABLE_NAME_BOOKS, contentValues, selection, selection_args);
        return count;
    }

    public void deleteBookInformation(String book_title,SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase){
    String selection = BookContent.NewBookInfo.BOOK_TITLE+ "  =?";
    String [] selection_args = {book_title};
    sqLiteDatabase.delete(BookContent.NewBookInfo.TABLE_NAME_BOOKS, selection, selection_args);
}
```

**Edit as asked activity_book_info.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.kasutwentyseven.gui4selfshelf.Books.BookInfoActivity"
    android:background="@color/Background">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/yourbookinfo"
        android:id="@+id/yourbookinfo"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textColor="@color/Textcolor"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/yourbookinfo"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout5">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/passed_bookimage" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/passed_booktitle" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/passed_bookauthor" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/passed_bookdate" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/passed_bookrating" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/passed_bookshelf" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout5"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout6">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/btn_update"
            android:id="@+id/button_update"
            android:onClick="updateBookInfo"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/btn_delete"
            android:id="@+id/btn_delete_book"
            android:onClick="deleteBook"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout6">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/secret_edittext_title" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: could you post your layout file?

Comment: I suppose the Toasts show that there are indeed database rows updated/deleted. If this is the case, the next step would be to show the changes in the ListView. The database and the ListView are normally not tightly linked, for that you would need to work with a CursorLoader/ SimpleCursorAdapter. So after the changes to the db, you have to load the data into the ListVIew like you did in the beginning .

Comment: @0X0nosugar Ok. but what happens than with the "old" data

Comment: you mean somethin like:
`bookDBHelper.addInformations(blob,title, author, date, rating, shelf, sqLiteDatabase1);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Data Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        bookDBHelper.close();`

Comment: no, I'm sorry that's a misunderstanding. Let's assume you have called the update method and the database is updated. Then you finish the detail activity and go back to the list activity and the data there is unchanged. That's the problem?

Comment: yes, thats what I was talking about. I click update, i get a Toast back. Data updated; then I return to the listview and nothing is update neither deleted

Comment: Exactly. That happens because the list activity was paused while you were editing the book details. But it never was finished (destroyed). So when you finished the details activity, you just resumed the list activity which kept the ListView data all the time because that's most efficient for android. (cont)

Comment: Okay, that seems logic, do you have an idea, how i can get rid of my problem?

Comment: You have to reload the data from database when the ListActivity is resumed. At least that's one way of doing it. Not the most efficient but it would work. Without the list activity code it's hard to be more specific.

Comment: is there a reload method which I can call in my updateBookInfo method?

Shell I upload all my other activities here?

Comment: let's continue this discussion in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101799/discussion-between-0x0nosugar-and-k-horst)

Comment: Sorry, I cant talk with you in the chat, I am new to stackoverflow so I dont have that much reputations.

You were totally right, If I edit data click update. Close the app and reopen it, I see the edited data. 

I tried to implement 

`bookListDataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` at the end of my updateBookInfo method

Unfortunately this works in a kind of way, because the app is crashing and restarting again :D

Comment: Sorry that the chat does not work for you :( But please, **don't** try to update the List from the details activity!

Comment: In the list activity, you can override "onResume()" and there you can call "bookListDataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();"

Comment: So it worked ;) Thanks for the help. 
Here my solution. 
I added:
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BookDataListActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent); 

to the updatebookinfo

and onResume method at the list activitiy

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @0x0nosugar (thanks for that)
 I found a solution:

to the updatebookinfo:
I added:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BookDataListActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

and for deleting:

```
    public void DeleteData(){
    btn_delete_book.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Integer deletedRows = bookDBHelper.deleteDate(passedbooktitle.getText().toString());
            if (deletedRows > 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Book deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BookDataListActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Book not deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    });
```

At BookDBHelper:

```
    public Integer deleteDate (String book_title){
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String selection = BookContent.NewBookInfo.BOOK_TITLE+ " = ?";
    String[] selection_args = {book_title};
    return sqLiteDatabase.delete(BookContent.NewBookInfo.TABLE_NAME_BOOKS,selection, selection_args);
}
```

method at the list activitiy:

```
    @Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    bookListDataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Comment: You know, the way you are starting the list activity now, you could call "finish();" there right after starting the details activity and do the same for the details activity after (re)starting the list activity. That way, you would not risk that the user presses "back" and navigates to an older version of the activity. This may never happen, but I like to be on the safe side :)

Comment: @0X0nosugar I have to disturb you again. My deleting operation doesnt wok. 

I edited and added the deleteBook method at my BookInfoactivity and the deleteBookInformation to the BookDBHelper Activity. 

I get the response book deleted but after resuming the BookListActivity the Book isnt deleted. Any suggestions?

Comment: well, your Toast success message is "self-certified" ;) As with "update()" you can check the return value of "delete()". If it isn't equal to 1 then you know there's something wrong with the query (like row was obviously in database but your query "selection" did not match the desired row) BTW, this may be a typo here on SO but make sure you   write " = ?" in the query, not " =?"

Comment: @0X0nosugar you were right with my " book deleted " ;) I added a count like @ my  update method. So my books dont get deleted unfortunately. 

Do you have an idea, how I will get it work=

Comment: I found a very nice step-by-step guide today on "how to deal with database problems". Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34991954/5015207)  will help. If it looks too complicated, I think you're down to logging (with *android.util.Log*) everything connected to the database calls. The advantage compared to Toasts/ live debugging is that the Logcat entries can be re-read as often as one needs to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101885/discussion-between-k-horst-and-0x0nosugar).